# Instance method to return name of attribute to which it assigns a value

Tags: python, class, variable-assignment

Any way to return name of instance attribute in method it calls on assignment?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.not_relevant = 0
        self.name_to_return = self.assign_own_name()
    
    def assign_own_name(self):
        return "name_to_return"  # to replace 

assert MyClass().name_to_return == 'name_to_return'
```

Use case: multiple attribute are initialized and value supplying instance method operates on basis of attribute name.

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.name_1 = do('name_1')
        ...
        self.name_n = do('name_n')
    
    def do(self, x):
        return x  # e.g. db query
```

Comment: This is so obviously impossible, that I suspect I must be misunderstanding what you're asking.  The assignment to `self.name_to_return` is something that happens entirely after the call to `self.assign_own_name()` has finished; the method cannot possibly return a different value depending on what's going to be done with that value in the future.

Comment: @jasonharper Seems odd as it can lead to repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override the setattr dunder method, you can do it like this:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(Class, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        return name

_class = Class()

print(_class.__setattr__('foo', 'bar'))
print(_class.foo)
```

**Output:**

```
foo
bar
```

Whilst...

```
_class.foo = 'bar'
```

...would still be syntactically correct you can't get the return value from such an assignment. If assignment expressions (walrus operator) worked with attributes then it would be easy but that's not allowed

Comment: How do you set an attribute within `__init__`? Tried `self.__setattr__('b', 2)()`.

Comment: @aeiou In the same way that you did it in your code. Or you could call *self.__setattr__(name, value)*

Comment: Thanks! Could overwriting `setattr` dunder have any consequences if one does not use it in class otherwise?

Comment: @aeiou The change to this dunder method adds functionality. It does not take anything away. Therefore I can't see how or why there would be any negative side-effects

Comment: Now I understand, nice idea!